# How to use ScrollIntoView for ListView in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ControlTemplate to show Items in ListView. ListView is having 500+ items. I am preserving the state and getting selected item from XML and sending it to listview to select it by default for next navigation to the screen.

My problem is How can I set selected item (which may be present in last i.e. out of view) by xaml. ViewModel doesn't know about any UI control, so I cant apply ScrollIntoView method in ViewModel.

Can I use any Setter or Style to do this?

Please suggest.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Could you provide a code example? Do you bind a ViewModel property (e.g. MySelectedItem) to the ListView SelectedItem property?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently done this with a DataGrid. The trick is to attach a custom Behavior to your View. Like that.

```
<ListView ... >
    <iy:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ext:ScrollIntoViewBehavior />
    </iy:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ...
</ListView>
```

And the assocciated class:

```
public class ScrollIntoViewBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListView)
        {
            ListView grid = (sender as ListView);
            if (grid.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                grid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    grid.UpdateLayout();
                    grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some things to be aware of:

- Add a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity assembly
- Add the corrsponding namespace in the view: xmlns:iy=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity